# Magnific-popup: how to disable the opening of a popup on some items?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, magnific-popup

I use this template : http://bootstrapbay.com/preview/ztheme-mulipurpose-responsive-template-B8068D9

It uses 'magnific popup' plugin to display a 1280x720 image when you click on an item of the galery.

I want to avoid the display of this 1280x720 image when an item of the grid view is clicked (I just want to open another page with an href but the magnific popup plugin overrides the href). How can I do to avoid the display of this 1280x720 image ?

Note that it does not work to remove the inclusion of the magnific popup script because the grid view does not load anymore in this case.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the solution of removing the inclusion of the magnific popup script doesn't work is that although the script not exist, the initialization of the plugin still exist in http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/js/page/page.home.js:

```
$('#owl-our-work').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
    type: 'image'
        // other options
});
```

And that throw an error that causes that the next script doesn't work:

```
$("#owl-our-work").owlCarousel({
    paginationSpeed: 500,
    autoPlay: 4000,
    items: 2,
    itemsCustom: [
        [0, 2],
        [450, 2]
    ]

});
```

So, you have 2 options:

1. Remove the code in snippet 1.
2. Block the `click` event of the `a` tag. How you do this? You can add a script **after** the script `<script src="assets/js/page/page.home.js"></script>` like this:

```js
// DON'T COPY THIS! This is the old script in "page.home.js"
//MAGINFIC POPUP
$('#owl-our-work').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
    type: 'image'
        // other options
});

/* YOU SHOULD COPY THIS CODE */
$('#owl-our-work').off('click');
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

img {
  width:100px;
}

.item {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="owl-our-work" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/lightbox.gif" class="img-wrapper rounded">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/1.png" alt="theme-img">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/lightbox.gif" class="img-wrapper rounded">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/2.png" alt="theme-img">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/lightbox.gif" class="img-wrapper rounded">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/3.png" alt="theme-img">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/lightbox.gif" class="img-wrapper rounded">
      <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/assets/images/portfolio/4.png" alt="theme-img">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To unbind it from magnific popup you can use:

```
$('#mylink').off('click');
```